# ELF Parser to separate data of program

Tags: c, elf

Using ELF Parser, how can I separate the address and data part of a program?

Comment: Is ELF Parser a particular program, or just any way of parsing an ELF file?  What do you mean by "address part", and how is it opposed to data?  Do you mean "code"?   You can't expect any answers unless you clarify this question a great deal.

Comment: i meant that from any program code, i need to seperate its data and associated memory address. eg: int a; means i need to seperate variable a and its address and display it. This seperation must be from an ELF file

Answer (score 1):

I think you are speaking about the symbol table in the elf file. The symbol table is a separate section in the elf file which will give the addresses of all data and functions.

To do so you will have to read each section header table in the location pointed by e_shoff( from the elf header) in the file. For each section header, check the type of the section. IF the type is 2(SHT_SYMTAB as per elf specification), read the corresponding sh_size from the location sh_offset to get the symbol table.

Find the elf specification [here](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/elf/elf.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [ELFIO library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfio/). It contains WriteObj and Writer examples. By using the library, you will be able to create/modify ELF binary files (including particular sections filtering).